# Is I2C master to Master communication possible?

Tags: embedded, fpga, xilinx, i2c, digital-logic

Is it possible for an I2C master device to communicate with another I2C master device ?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes!  As long as it specifies that it can do Multi Master operation, then it can communicate with another Master device.  There is a clock synchronization procedure that two masters need to perform.  To see how that works, read this PDF, section 4.3.1

[I2C FPGA Core from Opencores](http://opencores.org/svnget,i2c?file=%2Ftrunk%2F%2Fdoc%2Fi2c_specs.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

Yes it's possible..
But clock synchronization is important part.
Hope u go through above given PDF.